# How to Display Image Meta underneath EVERY image in EVERY post

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails, post-meta

First off, I want to say thank you for taking the time to even read this, I really do appreciate the help this site and it's community has given me thus far.

---

i have looked forever to be able to find a way to append (display inside an added div) some image meta data just below EVERY image in EVERY single post. I have found some stuff for NextGen Gallery and some other things, but that is way too much bloat, I just want to attach a div and a couple spans, with a little php thrown in there!

I am building a fairly huge magazine style website, and a lot of the images will need to be accredited to photographers who don't directly work for the site.

I have been searching for a way to do this via php, not js. I like the plugin [Media Custom Fields](http://vimeo.com/18757227) it lets me add a couple extra lines of meta to every media file, which is perfect. I don't need any help with pulling that meta out and displaying it once I know how to append something to every image.

Meaning that, after someone can help me find out how to add stuff to all the images, i should be able to take it from there!

I know that this code does not work or make sense, but maybe some of you can figure out exactly what I need from this example, I hope! :

```
    add_filter('image', 'add_stuff',);
    function add_stuff($image_meta) 
        {
            $image_meta = '';

            $author_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, "tamcf_author_name", TRUE );
            $author_website = get_post_meta($post->ID, "tamcf_author_website", TRUE);

                if (is_single() && (is_image())
                    {
                    foreach( $images as $image ) 
                        {
                        $image_meta .= '<div class="extra_image_meta"><span>' . $author_name . '</span><span>' . $author_website . '</span></div>';
                        }
                    } 
            $image .= $image_meta
            return $image
        }
```

That is pretty much what I need to happen, if you all can understand that!

Comment: just a note, I always insert my images at the "large" size. and yes I only want the snippet to append the meta to image files, no other type of media. And, at the moment until I get this figured out, I do want to add it to every image that shows up in every post without exception. Hope that stuff helps, still at a loss here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATE

I did not test this method, but it is not very old. It adds custom meta information to the caption section of the image, which can then be styled as needed. Again, I did not try the method, and I am not a coder, but from reading through the tutorial, it sounds like it fits your needs.

[Add Custom Meta Fields to Media Attachments in WordPress](http://www.kevinleary.net/add-custom-meta-fields-media-attachments-wordpress/)

#### Original Answer

I think this article from wpbeginner might be exactly what you need. I have used this exact method before.

[How to Add Additional Fields to the WordPress Media Uploader](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-the-wordpress-media-uploader/)

Comment: Thanks @TravisPflanz but I mentioned above that there is a very nice little plugin that I m using that allows me to do exactly what that article does, and by the way this article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress/ from tuts helps to do it too. The specific problem I am having is that I want the fields to be added to EVERY image in EVERY single post. NOT just on the attachment pages or using a template tag like they suggest. I wish the answer to my question was that simple, but thank you for trying! If you have anything else, Great!

Comment: and actually the comment by ALLEN about 10 comments down on this page: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress/comment-page-2/#comments i think is getting close, but that is as close as I have gotten, and it isn't working yet... I hope someone can add to this a bit, I always seem to post on weekends late at night, lol! there aren't nearly as many of us active on here at those times and questions often get looked over :(

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to add a snippet to my functions file in my theme that does this work of adding the meta to all of the images for me

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question originally. I found this old piece of code. I'm no coder and cannot get it to work, but it seems like it could get you a step closer. http://wpengineer.com/126/image-metadata-in-wordpress/

Comment: I added an update. It sounds like what you may need.

Comment: thats ok, I think you are still misunderstanding... The example you provided, again, shows the meta only on attachment pages and NOT in posts. I don't use an attachment.php file or any mime-type files. THis is actually why I am asking the question. I don't use a lightbox and don't use an attachment.php file because i don't want the reader to stop reading the content. I just want the meta to show under EVERY image in ALL single-posts. Thank you so much for doing more research though, It's nice to know that someone cares :)

Comment: I know you are trying, but you are missing the point!

Comment: I think you need to read that ENTIRE post. It explicitly discusses displaying the meta data ON the post page inside the image caption, with every image. " Using the two attachment custom fields we create above for “Credit text” and “Credit Link” we can add an additional paragraph to display the image credit information in the shortcode in WordPress."

Comment: I'm reading it, and testing something now, if I am wrong, please excuse me. I do not mean to be rude in the slightest, I actually hadn't noticed the update until I had already written the reply. I will post back here in a few once I've gone over it a bit more :)

Comment: This in combination with the other resources that it points to, and the ones that you and I have discussed previously, seems it may be a very close remedy to my problem! I am sorry there was some confusion. I will try and write something concise and a bit cleaner this evening and tomorrow, and then post it here as an answer sometime tomorrow evening. I will make sure that it displays correctly on all screens in the back end, that it saves the values correctly, and that it shows up on the front end correctly. Thanks for the research and the good find @TravisPflanz   Kudos :)

Comment: it works, a lot of tweaking needed, well not A LOT, but it does what I needed and a heck of a lot better than I could have even begun to do it! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I'll post the code if I do anything cool to it, otherwise I will refrain ;)

Comment: Glad it worked. I would be interested in seeing the code.

Comment: I am using the code pretty much as is. I am changing the styling and adding some extra fields, but nothing major. In the future I may implement a checkbox field that when checked returns true. This will allow me to write a conditional statement checking for that field. Basically enabling me to say "check this box if you want this to show under each picture"... but for now, if anyone is interested, the code that is linked to works out of the box pretty flawlessly.